# N25Q256A13EF840 vs MT25QL256ABA1EW9-0SIT

Tags: spi

I learned that QSPI chip from Micron N25Q256A13EF840F is getting obsolete. I found a similar device MT25QL256ABA1EW9-0SIT from Micron. It did not work when I replaced it on a board. It does not even give me the manufacturer ID
Is  N25Q256A13EF840F drop-in replacement for  MT25QL256ABA1EW9-0SIT ?

Below is the datasheet link for N25Q256A13EF840F 
https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/nor-flash/serial-nor/n25q/n25q_256mb_3v.pdf

Below is the datasheet link for MT25QL256ABA1EW9-0SIT
https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/nor-flash/serial-nor/mt25q/die-rev-a/mt25q_qljs_l_256_aba_0.pdf

Comment: It would be easier to compare when it is known what differences to look out for, and what to ignore. What commands and features are used on the old chip?

Comment: @Justme I did compare, I am expecting at least to receive manufacturer ID. I do not get it.

Comment: We are expecting at least to receive a link to the datasheet for each part. I'm not familiar with either part number so you might want to explain what you are using them for and what parameters do you think are important. A schematic would be good too. Hit the edit link below your question.

Comment: Datasheet link added